# Introductory Reference for Asymptotically Safe Gravity

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization, quantum-gravity

I have a fairly solid understanding of "classical" quantum field theory (Weinberg 1 & 2) and also of General Relativity with its various formulations. Being one that works in the field of canonical quantization of gravity I never had the opportunity to dive into Asymptotically Safe Gravtity. I am interested in understanding better what the program is, but I don't have too much time to read a full book on the subject, like Percacci's.

Could anyone provide references on an introductory level, for someone interested in understanding the program but not specialising in it?
Also a brief list of the prerequisites for the reference provided will be a nice addon.

Answer (score 0):

These days, there are already (at least) two textbooks
on the subject, "An Introduction to Covariant Quantum Gravity and Asymptotic Safety" by Roberto Percacci, and "Quantum Gravity and the Functional Renormalization Group, The Road towards Asymptotic Safety" by Martin Reuter and Frank Saueressig.

Comment: As i specified in the post, i don't have enough time to read a full textbook at least for now, i was looking just for more introductory lecture notes to the topic than full textbooks on the subject